# How to create an alias in ansible for a mysql database

Tags: ansible, build-script

I'm having trouble defining an alias for my MySQL database in my inventory file in ansible. I can easily create one for my EC2 instance by using.:

```
ansible_ssh_host
ansible_ssh_port
ansible_ssh_user
```

Like this:

```
[webserver]
some-hostname ansible_ssh_host=some-subdomain-of-amazon
```

But it doesn't use ssh to connect to the database instance. How do I create an alias for that group

```
[databases]
some-hostname ansible_mysql_host=some-subdomain-of-amazon
```

I can't seem to find anything on this in the documentation.

// Ulrik McArdle

Answer (score 0):

The names you provide in ansible hosts files are not known to DNS. They are not CNAMES. Thus, you can only refer to them using ansible tools (e.g. `ansible` and `ansible-playbook`).

The `ansible_ssh_host`, `ansible_ssh_port` and `ansible_ssh_user` and Ansible keywords you can use to tell ansible tools 'hey, host `foo` has this ip, and you can connect via ssh on port `ansible_ssh_port`n, etc... They just have no meaning outside ansible.

This being said, `ansible_mysql_host` of course is not a valid keyword.
So I don't really know what you are trying to achieve here, but if you need to adress your mysql server using a DNS name (which I would not really recommend depending on the driver you're using), you have to use a real DNS entry, that can be resolved from your clients.

An option is to add a name in your client's `/etc/hosts` file, or create a Route53 entry using the route53 ansible module.

Comment: I know they can not be used outside Ansible. It's because I would like to use the host name to create the host_vars folder or am I missing something. The endpoints in AWS is very long and it would be nice to shorten them with an alias.